# How to find the local directories for Heroku apps?

Tags: heroku

I have a few old Heroku apps on my local machine and am not sure where they're stored any more. Is there any way to somehow locate them with the Heroku CLI?

Neither `heroku apps:table` nor `heroku apps` provides this info as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Neither `heroku apps:table` nor `heroku apps` provides this info as far as I can tell

Why should they? Heroku doesn't care about where your local copies live. There can be zero or many of them for each app, and they can live on any number of machines.

Your best bet is probably to search for Git repositories using whatever tools are available for your operating system. For example, on a Unixy machine you might run

```sh
find ~ -type d -name .git
```

to look for directories named `.git/` in your home directory. For each repository you find you could look for remotes containing `git.heroku.com`. Something like this should get you started:

```sh
for GIT_DIR in $(find ~ -type d -name .git); do
  cd "$GIT_DIR"
  if git remote -v | grep git.heroku.com >/dev/null; then
    echo "$GIT_DIR contains a Heroku remote"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, I was able produce results with your script. "Why should they? Heroku doesn't care about where your local copies live." I thought it might be storing additional data somewhere since the CLI commands to print out app info can be run globally.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the CLI commands to print out app info get their data from Heroku, not from your local system. You're right, though: they could conceivably remember where things are.